# Esperanto translation of all site titles

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Even if all the sites were in English, it would still be a good idea to give parallel Esperanto translations of the site names. However, some sites are in fact not in English, making it all the more obvious that such parallel translations would be useful.

Esperanto is merely the optimal choice (because of its ease of learning) for such parallel translations. If some other language, such as French, were chosen for the role, about 80% of the cited benefit would still obtain.

“English is just badly pronounced French.”
-- Georges Clemenceau

Comment: If I have a site title in my own language I would assume I can ask questions using the same, which is obviously not allowed. So how would it be a good idea?

Comment: Esperanto is, while being a great idea, commonly less known than even latin for the broader audience. I can't imagine how that would improve anything.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure what the benefit of this is.

While it is *allegedly* the most common constructed language, the largest estimate I can find on wikipedia is about... [10 million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto). I'm pretty sure there's languages in our userbase - Hindi, or say chinese with more speakers. Heck, my native tamil, spoken in one state in india, parts of Sri Lanka, immigrant populations in south east asia and by diaspora almost certainly has more speakers.

This seems a lot of work nearly no benefit, especially where sites are english by default.

Comment: Whoa, you're a Tamil speaker?

Comment: Yup I am. Amusingly there's quite a few I've come across on SE, including a former CM ;p

Answer (score 3):

> However, some sites are in fact not in English, making it all the more obvious that such parallel translations would be useful.

No. Esperanto won't be a solution to fit them all well.

Esperanto is an artificial niche language, mostly based on latin language idioms, and only a very narrowed audience will be capable of understanding it.

[Google translate](https://translate.google.de/) does it's job well already, and you can use it to translate questions (and titles) that you don't understand.

Comment: How many people speak Esperanto is irrelevant, since Esperanto is so easy to decipher. Esperanto’s ‘niche’ runs from the north pole to the south pole.